# Ajax POST not posting model to the controller in asp.net core 6

Tags: javascript, ajax, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to POST data to my controller from an event raised from Kendo dialog. But, the model is always coming as null. I tried various steps which were mentioned in StackOverflow itself, but none of them works.

**My Ajax call**

```
function onSubmit(e) {
          
           var myModel={
                  Id:0,
                  RoleNameEn:$('#UserRolePopup').find('#RoleNameEn')[0].value,
                  RoleNameAr:$('#UserRolePopup').find('#RoleNameAr')[0].value,
                  IsActive:$('#UserRolePopup').find('#IsActive')[0].value,
                  CreatedBy:0,
                  CreatedDate:"",
                  ModifiedBy:0,
                  ModifiedDate:""
           };

           $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "@Url.Action("Delete", "UserRole")", //'/UserRole/Create'
              contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
              data: JSON.stringify(myModel) ,
              success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
              },
              error: function (result, status) {
                console.log(result);
              }
            });

        }
```

**My HTML**

```
<div id="example">  
    @(Html.Kendo().Dialog()
    .Name("dialog")
    .Title("Add/Edit User Role")
    .Content("<div id='UserRolePopup'>  <div class='form-group; k-content'> <label for='RoleNameEn'>User role English</label>    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='RoleNameEn' placeholder='Role name in english'/>      </div> <div class='form-group'>    <label for='RoleNameAr'>User role Arabic</label>    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='RoleNameAr' placeholder='Role name in Arabic'>      </div>  <div class='form-check'>        <input class='form-check-input' type='checkbox' value='' id='IsActive'>    <label class='form-check-label' for='IsActive'>Is Active</label>  </div> </div>")
    .Width(400)
    .Modal(true)
    .Actions(actions =>
    {
    actions.Add().Text("Cancel");
    actions.Add().Text("Submit").Primary(true).Action("onSubmit");
    })
    .Events(ev => ev.Close("onClose").Open("onOpen"))
    )
</div>
```

Now the data captured is passed to the controller.
[image]

You can see the value is getting passed to the controller.

**My Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Delete([FromBody] UserRoleDTO userRoleDTO)
        {
            return new JsonResult(userRoleDTO);
        }
```

**My `Program.cs` file**

```
builder.Services.AddMvc()
           .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
           options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
              new DefaultContractResolver());

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

**Things I tried**

- I used `[FromBody],[FromForm]` - Both didn't work
- Changed `datatype` in ajax to be `text` and passed to a method with string as parameter - Did not work
- Tried various ways passing the `JSON`. Did not work
- Changed the `JSON` to `NewtonSoft.Json`. That also did not work

Can someone tell me if there is any configuration which is missing or why this is not working

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60424860/sending-array-object-data-in-javascript-to-asp-net-core-controller-using-ajax

Comment: Tried. Does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was due to a `datatype` mismatch in one of my `property` in the model. `IsActive` is `Int` in model and since I was passing an empty string it was not deserializing properly.

I debugged this by using the below code

```
   [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Delete(UserRoleDTO userRoleDTO)
    {
        using (var bodyReader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body))
        {
            Task<string> requests = bodyReader.ReadToEndAsync();

            UserRoleDTO? userRole = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<UserRoleDTO>(requests.Result);
        }

        return new JsonResult(userRoleDTO);
    }
```

`requests.Result` was having he `JSON` data which I pass in the `Ajax` Call. But `deserializing` was throwing error.

Once the issue was fixed, changed the input parameter to be `[FromBody] UserRoleDTO userRoleDTO` and now it has the values inside the input parameter

[image]

I still wonder why the actual method in the controller(delete) works even when it cannot match the model datatypes.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've been encountering a bunch of these little pitfalls in converting a older .net project to core.  For sure  it was more forgiving when  casting properties (my string was null instead of empty).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try to use the model to create a new object, I tried it, it works fine.

You can refer to the following code.

**Delete.cshtml:**

```
@model AjaxTest1.Models.UserRoleDTO
<div id="example">
        <div id='UserRolePopup'>  
            <div class='form-group; k-content'> 
                <label for='RoleNameEn'>User role English</label>    
                <input type='text' class='form-control' id='RoleNameEn' placeholder='Role name in english'/>
            </div> 
            <div class='form-group'>    
                <label for='RoleNameAr'>User role Arabic</label>    
                <input type='text' class='form-control' id='RoleNameAr' placeholder='Role name in Arabic'/>      
            </div>  
            <div class='form-check'>        
                <input class='form-check-input' type='checkbox' value='' id='IsActive'/>    
                <label class='form-check-label' for='IsActive'>Is Active</label>  
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" onclick="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
        </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    function onSubmit() {
            @Model mydata=new Object();
            mydata.Id = 0;
            mydata.RoleNameEn = $('#UserRolePopup').find('#RoleNameEn')[0].value;
            mydata.RoleNameAr = $('#UserRolePopup').find('#RoleNameAr')[0].value;
            mydata.IsActive = $('#UserRolePopup').find('#IsActive')[0].value;
            mydata.CreatedBy = "0";
            mydata.CreatedDate = "";
            mydata.ModifiedBy = "0";
            mydata.ModifiedDate = "";
            
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "/Home/Delete",
              contentType: 'application/json',
              data: JSON.stringify(mydata) ,
              success: function (result) {
                alert("success");
                console.log(result);
              },
              error: function (result, status) {
                alert("123");
                console.log(result);
              }
            });
    }
    
</script>
```

Please note that you need to use `@model` to refer to your model.

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Delete([FromBody]UserRoleDTO userRoleDTO)
{
     return Json(userRoleDTO);
}
```

**Test Result:**

[userRoleDTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6jcd.png)

[developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBF6N.png)

Sorry I don't have enough points so I can't upload screenshots directly.